# How to migration in realm for new table in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, realm-migration

I add a new table to my realm database. For migration, I try at this way:

```
 realm.schema.create("AddTodoModel")
      .addField("id", Long::class.java, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
      .addField("title", String::class.java , FieldAttribute.INDEXED)
      .addField("list", RealmList::class.java , FieldAttribute.INDEXED)
      .addField("color", Int::class.java , FieldAttribute.INDEXED)
```

And this is AddTodoModel class:

```
open class AddTodoModel(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Long,
    var title: String,
    var list: RealmList<TodoModel>,
    var color: Int
) : RealmObject() {
    constructor() : this(0, "", RealmList<TodoModel>(), R.color.black)
}
```

And when start the app, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Use addRealmObjectField() instead to add fields that link to other RealmObjects: list
```

I just get this error when the app updated. So, How to fix this error and migrate to a new version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying some way, I found the solution. Maybe someone needs this:
I create a list as TodoModel class in the database, But I miss to create a migration for that. And also I need to use `FieldAttribute.REQUIRED` instead of `FieldAttribute.INDEXED`. So this is the final migration code:

```
 realm.schema.create("AddTodoModel")
      .addField("id", Long::class.java, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
      .addField("title", String::class.java, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
      .addRealmListField(
           "list",
           realm.schema.create("TodoModel")
           .addField("isDone", Boolean::class.java, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
      )
      .addField("color", Int::class.java, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
```